# Swift: Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

Two Classes:

```
import UIKit
struct ListSection {
    var rows : [ListRow]?
    var sectionTitle : String?
}


import UIKit
struct ListRow {
    var someString: String?
}
```

Now when I try to append:

```
var row = ListRow()
row.someString = "Hello"

var sections = [ListSection]()
sections[0].rows.append(row) // I get the following error:
//Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type (ListRow)'
```

If I try this:

```
sections[0].rows?.append(row) // I get the following error:
//Will never be executed
```

How do I append to `rows` in `section[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `ListSection` to the sections array first

```
    var sections = [ListSection]()
    var firstSection = ListSection(rows:[ListRow](), sectionTitle:"title")
    sections.append(firstSection)

    var row = ListRow()
    row.someString = "Hello"
    sections[0].rows!.append(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with fixing the sections[0] problem: There is no sections[0] at the time you attempt to access it. You need to append at least one section before accessing sections[0].

Comment: Thanks.  What would be the syntax to create a section[0] if it doesn't exists?

Comment: For example `sections.append(listSection)` where `listSection` is an existing ListSection instance...

Answer (score 1):

You need to at least have one `ListSection` in your `sections` array, but you also need the `rows` array in each `ListSection` to be initialized or empty instead of a nil Optional.

```
struct ListRow {
    var someString: String?
}

struct ListSection {
    var rows = [ListRow]()
    var sectionTitle : String?
}

var row = ListRow()
row.someString = "Hello"

var sections = [ListSection]()

sections.append(ListSection())

sections[0].rows.append(row)
```